# fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxxx/_git/xxxx/': Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: github

I am unable to update or push my changes to GIT.  This is the error that I am getting:

```
Opening repositories:
D:\Source\repos\RevaVase
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
unable to access 'https://wxxx.visualstudio.com/Rxxxx/_git/Rxxx/': Send failure: Connection was reset
```

I tried to clone a brand new GIT Repository that I created as a test. The same error occurred:

[image]

I also tried to reset all the Folder permission on my local drive with the "takeown" call as well as the "git config --global --add safe.directory *".  Nothing worked.  The Visual Studio Credentialsfor GIT Changes does not seem to connect to the xxx.visualstudsio.com/ url and it takes a long time to show-up if I w3it, but still no connection to GIT is available.

Is there anything I can do to get it back?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for my Windows 11 build, my IPv6 was causing an issue.  First, the Upload stream was very slow and was hindering the Visual Studio Publishing process.  Second, the GIT Source in Visual Studio was picking up the IPv6 settings, and could not find the GIT Repository for my visualstudio.com repository of projects.  In order to solve this issue, I had to disable the IPv6 setting from the Network settings and deselect it from the Network Adapter Options, Advanced setting properties.